# Do I need socket.io-client on browser-side of things?

Tags: node.js, bower, socket.io-1.0

**EDIT: The answer appears to be *no*.**

I'm new to Node.js, bower and Socket.IO and I'm not sure what I need for my purpose.

I'm making an app that has a frontend (where browsers connect) and a backend (a single Node.js server).

What do I need to create a Socket.IO server instance on the backend? What do I need on the client-side? Does the Socket.IO package contain both?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, however my reading comprehension is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install socket.io using below command

```
npm install socket.io
```

and the call socket.io in your server js File

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```

And the create connection in your server js file

```
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
fs.readFile('index.html', function(Error,data){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.write(data);
res.end();
});
});
server = http.createServer(app);
var IO = io.listen(server);
server.listen(3000);
IO.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
socket.on('msg_to_server', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
        });
        });
```

Add this script inside head Tag in your index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

in your index.html create socketio connection

```
var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:3000");
```

send some data to server following way

```
socketio.emit('msg_to_server',{ message : 'some data' });
```

Comment: Excellent examples. I have a question about the last two examples though. Do I need the socket.io-client bower package (or <script> include) for them to work at client-side?

Comment: var socketio = io.connect("127.0.0.1:3000"); and socketio.emit('msg_to_server',{ message : 'some data' }); comes under <script> tag in your index.html page

Comment: Yeah, but which socket.io library do I need to include? The "socket.io" one, or the "socket.io-client" one?

Comment: socket.io. not "socket.io-client"

Comment: Well, I just don't understand anything anymore. For what purpose did they make the "client" one, if all you need is socket.io on both ends?

Comment: i am using only socket.io for sends and receiving the data from server. i am not familiar with "socket.io-client".

Comment: In my experience the npm module for socket.io includes the client version. When you create the socket.io server as described above it will automatically create an endpoint that you can use in your HTML: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.

Comment: yes sukima you are right. i forgot to mention that. Thanks.